# How can I authenticate asp.net web application with custom login server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, single-sign-on

I am making custom Single-Sign-On service with asp.net core. I made login server which returns JWT token in the cookie with validation. I would like to connect my web application to the login server, so the web application recognize if the user is logged in or not by login server.
Is it possible to do it with **startup.cs** setting in the web application? And if so how can I make it? I don't want to put the token checking process in every actions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need an OAuth/OIDC framework. One example would be IdentityServer4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, in asp.net core we could provide the jwtbear authentication validation to check if the user login or not. All these things is provided at the web application not login server.  If you send the token to the login server how the web application know the user is login or not.

Normally, we will directly check the user token is valid or not on the web application side.

We could set the login server and web application use the same Issuer, Audience and SecretKey.

Then we you could directly validate the user in the web application instead of login server.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

Login server generate token:

```
    public static string GetToken3()
    {

        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes
        ("YourKey-2374-OFFKDI940NG7:56753253-tyuw-5769-0921-kfirox29zoxv");
        //Generate Token for user 
        var JWToken = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: "http://localhost:45092/",
            audience: "http://localhost:45092/",
            claims: new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Users2222" )
},
            notBefore: new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).DateTime,
            expires: new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)).DateTime,
            //Using HS256 Algorithm to encrypt Token  
            signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials
            (new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
        );
        string token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(JWToken);
        return token;
    }
```

web application validate token:

```
        //Provide a secret key to Encrypt and Decrypt the Token
        var SecretKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes
             ("YourKey-2374-OFFKDI940NG7:56753253-tyuw-5769-0921-kfirox29zoxv");

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:45092/",
        ValidAudience = "http://localhost:45092/",
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
            SecretKey),
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a question. After I get a token from login server, how does the web application validate it directly? Where should I pass the token at?

Comment: You could see that the asp.net core has the authentication middleware which will use JWT authentication handler setting to validate the token.  You could pass the token in the request Authorization header. More details, you could refer to this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-json-web-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/).